# Breakpoints not appearing when trying to debug Fortran in VS Code on Ubuntu

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to be able to compile and debug fortran code in VS code, but there is no option to create a breakpoint in my file.
I have the following extensions installed:
[image: Extensions]

and my fortran file looks like this
[image]

But when I try to click to the left of the line numbers to add a breakpoint, I just can't. I've been following this youtube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XuNjA230e3k&t=205s) as I go along to try to set this up and it's all been the same up to this point, but I just don't seem to have the option to add a breakpoint to debug

Comment: please give your list of extensions as _text_ and not as an image. You can right click to copy their extension ID, and also please copy and paste the extension version number. also if the point of your code screenshot is just to show code, then it should also be text and not an image: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541